# ssm is not available after instance_running waiter is done

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-ssm

I want to start a stopped ec2 instance and run a bash script on it using ssm.

Here's the code I have:

```py
import boto3
instanceid = 'i-123456789'

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instance = ec2.Instance(instanceid)
response = instance.start()

waiter = boto3.client('ec2').get_waiter('instance_running')
waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[instanceid])

ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')
ssm_client.send_command(
        InstanceIds=[instanceid],
        DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
        Parameters={'commands': ['ls']})
```

It fails on [send_command](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.send_command) with an exception:

```
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidInstanceId: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation: Instances [[i-123456789]] not in a valid state for account
```

If I amend my code above with:

```py
import time
time.sleep(20)
```

Between the [waiter](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceRunning) and ssm_client, it works. But is there a better way to wait for ssm to be up, rather than sleeping?

Comment: It sounds like the issue is that you are running the ssm command before the ssm agent service is actually running on the instance: the *instance_running* condition that you are using will return as soon as the instance is ready, however that does not mean that the ssm agent service is operational. Instead of adding a random sleep statement, you could check the status of the service with SSH and wait until the service is operational

Comment: Or perhaps simpler, use `describe_instance_information()` in a loop until it returns the instance ID. This will signify that the instance is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Paolo suggestion added this check ([docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.describe_instance_information)):

```py
    for i in range(1, 100):
        response = ssm_client.describe_instance_information(Filters=[{'Key': 'InstanceIds', 'Values': [instanceid]}])
        if len(response["InstanceInformationList"]) > 0 and \
                response["InstanceInformationList"][0]["PingStatus"] == "Online" and \
                response["InstanceInformationList"][0]["InstanceId"] == instanceid:
            break
        time.sleep(1)
```